# I installed posh-git 1.1.0 with no errors, but don't see the git info on my command line. What do I do to get it to show up?

Tags: powershell, git, windows-11

I successfully installed posh-git 1.1.0 using the following actions:

```
c:\Users\username> PowerShellGet\Install-Module posh-git -Scope CurrentUser -Force
c:\Users\username>
```

But when I navigate to the git information in a git repo, I don't get anything on the command line:

```
C:\Users\username> cd .\source\repos\
C:\Users\username\source\repos> cd .\myproj\
C:\Users\username\source\repos\myproj>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

## Installing posh-git doesn't automatically use posh-git

Installing posh-git doesn't automatically run it for your profile. After installation of posh-git, you must then import it into your session to start using posh-git powershell session. You can set your profile to automatically use posh-git with the command:

```
C:\Users\username> Add-PoshGitToProfile
```

Then restart your powershell session. After this, git information will show up in the command line:

```
C:\Users\username> cd .\source\repos\
C:\Users\username\source\repos> cd .\myproj\
C:\Users\username\source\repos\myproj [develop ≡]>
```

See more options at the [Using posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#using-posh-git) section on the posh-git github repo.